# numpy masked array behaves differently when one dtype is an object

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking, recarray

say that I have the following two masked arrays declarations:

```
arr1 = ma.array([(1,2,"hello"),(10,20,"world!")],dtype=[("p1",int),("p2",float),("p3",object)])
arr1.mask["p1"][0] = True
arr1.mask["p2"][1] = True

arr2 = ma.array([(1,2,3),(10,20,30)],dtype=[("p1",int),("p2",float),("p3",int)])
arr2.mask["p1"][0] = True
arr2.mask["p2"][1] = True
```

as you can see the only (slight ?) difference is that the "p3" field is an object for `arr1` and an int for `arr2`.

Calling `arr2[0]` is OK and gives `(--, 2.0, 3)`.

However, when masking some elements of `arr1`, calling `arr1[0]` gives the following error:

`*** ValueError: Setting void-array with object members using buffer.`

Clearly, declaring one field as an object triggered some troubles but I have no single idea why.

What do you think about this and would you see some ways to circumvent that problem, keeping in mind that I would really need to access 'arr1[0]' on that way ?

thanks a lot

Eric

EDIT: this problem occurs with numpy version < 1.8. I tried with the latest version (1.8) and it is OK.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an array like this, giving names for each `dtype` field, [you are actually creating a `np.recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) or an array whose fields are accessed using attributes.

So, to access the first field of `arr1` you should do:

```
arr1['p1']
#masked_array(data = [-- 10],
#             mask = [ True False],
#       fill_value = 999999)
```

instead of `arr1[0]`.

---

EDIT: The 2-D solution would be something like:

```
b1m = np.array([[True, False, False],[False, True, False]])
b1 = np.ma.array([[1, 2, 'hello'],
                  [10, 20, 'world!']], mask=b1m, dtype=object)
b2m = np.array([[True, False, False],[False, True, False]])
b2 = np.ma.array([[1, 2, 3],
                  [10, 20, 30]], mask=b2m, dtype=object)
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. However, I still do not understand why my construction failed when one of the field is an object. Moreover, in the context of my project I would really need a row access to my masked array by `arr1[0]`

Comment: @PellegriniEric the problem is that the `recarray` is not a 2-D array, so you cannot access the items like `a[i,j]`, it is a kind of group of 1-D arrays, each one called by its field name. You could redesign your code to work with 2-D arrays though...

Comment: what would be an alternative design for the example given above keeping in mind that I would like to keep the masked array feature that allow to handle on a very general way the problem of missing/invalid value in my database ?

Comment: @PellegriniEric I've updated the answer with one possibility for the 2-D array solution...

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, this design does not fit my problem because it will consider everything to be an object making hard to track invalid entries. That's why I was looking for some ways to declare an array with several dtypes without assigning a label to each of them

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem occurs with numpy version < 1.8. I tried with the latest version (1.8) and it is OK. So I guess that I have to live with that ...

Thanks for your help.